# Journey Builder - Email Address Check

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, subscriber

I have 2 questions regarding Email Address present checks with Journey Builder.

1 - I have a 2nd DE, all connected in Data Designer, that contains Email Address only. How do I check to ensure that the email address in the journey is 'not present' in the DE? Is it simply "Email Address is null" here? For example, if Email Address is null (doesn't exist) go down Path 1. If Email is not null (does exist), go down Path 2.

2 - Am I able to check All Subscribers to see if the customer is Active? For example, if customer is currently Active, go down Path 1. If customer is Unsubscribed or Held, go down Path 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is easy, provided your subscriberkey relationship on the entry
   DE is also through EmailAddress. When a contact enters the journey,
   all decision splits in journey builder are evaluated against the
   contactKey linked in the data designer and the subscriberKey that
   enters the journey.
2. You cannot use data views in decision splits. Instead you can create a copy of your data views and run an hourly job to copy data
   from data views to standard data extension, link it in data designer
   and then use in the decision splits.

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes sense on #2. I was able to confirm that for #1, I just use the EmailAddress field in the 2nd DE and check to see if it's null or not null. Thanks again.